# Build a view-sum row programmatically in Drupal 8

Tags: view, hook, drupal-8

I have a table view with two numeric fields and some rows.

First task is, to build a third field where the two fields are multiplicated.
It is no problem for me, to build the sum with views_pre_render(\Drupal\views\ViewExecutable $view).

But i don't find a solution to get this new field in frontend.
Should I overwrite a given field of the node in view or should i build a new field?

And the second task is, to build a sum over all rows of the new field an output it in footer.

I am seeking for ours the different view-hooks in API but don't find the solution.

Could you please give me some hints?

Answer (score 0):

I put a new field to the content type with default 0.
And with mymodule_entity_presave(Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $entity) i did the multiplication of the other two fields and updated the new field with this value.

Put the new field to view and now I have the multiplicated value.

Next step is to build a sum row with total sum of the new field.

I would like to build a new Variable for Twig with a preprocess view-Function.

I tried this one mytheme_preprocess_views_view_table(&$variables), becaus it is a table view.
But i cant get the raw value in the foreach loop of the result.
What would be the best solution?